# Process to intersect with pre-trained word vectors with gensim 4.0.0

Tags: python, gensim

I'm trying to learn from an example which uses an older version of gensim. In particular, I have a section of code like:

```
word_vectors = Word2Vec(vector_size=word_vector_dim, min_count=1)
word_vectors.build_vocab(corpus_iterable)
word_vectors.intersect_word2vec_format(pretrained_dir + 'GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', binary=True)
```

My understanding is that this fills the word vector vocabulary with pre-trained word vectors when available. When the words in my vocabulary are not in the pretrained vectors, they are initialized to random values. However, the method `intersect_word2vec_format` doesn't exist in the latest version of gensim. What is the cleanest way to replicate this process in gensim 4.0.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.intersect_word2vec_format()` method still exists, but as an operation on a set of word-vectors, has moved to `KeyedVectors`. So in some cases, older code that had called the method on a `Word2Vec` model itself will need to call it on the model's `.wv` property, holding a `KeyedVectors` object, instead. EG:

```py
w2v_model = Word2Vec(vector_size=word_vector_dim, min_count=1)
w2v_model.build_vocab(corpus_iterable)
# (you'll likely need another workaround here, see below)
w2v_model.wv.intersect_word2vec_format(pretrained_dir + 'GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', binary=True)
```

However, you'll still hit some problems:

- It's always been at best an experimental, advanced feature – and not a part of any well-documented processes. So it's best used if you're able to [review its source code](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/5bec27767ad40712e8912d53a896cb2282c33880/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L1634), & understand what limits & tradeoffs will come with using such (partially)-pre-initialized word-vectors, maybe-further-trained or maybe-frozen (depending on the `vectors_lockf` values chosen).
- The equally experimental `vectors_lockf` functionality will now, in Gensim 4+, require manual initialization by the knowledgeable - & because `.intersect_word2vec_format()` assumes a particular pre-allocation, that method will break in Gensim 4.1 without an explicit workaround. See [this open issue for more details](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/3094#issuecomment-809763444).

Most generally: pre-initializing with other word-vectors is at best a fussy, advanced technique, so be sure to study the code, consider the potential tradeoffs, & carefully evaluate its effects on your end-results, before embracing it. It's not an easy, automatic, or well-characterized shortcut.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. May I ask a follow-up question? You say this is an advanced technique, and I believe you. However, I'm new enough to this space that it's not clear to me that this should be an advanced technique. It seems perfectly normal to have word-vectors that have been optimized but have others in your corpora that are not in the pre-trained word vectors. Can you comment on what IS the well-characterized approach? Always training vectors from scratch? I am not trying to do anything advanced, but rather am trying to learn the basics.

Comment: Yes, the best-characterized approach is training from scratch. Certainly lots of people *have* implemented various other ways to use prior vectors as a head-start, or tried to train new vectors into an existing space. But in this vein – related to idea of 'fine-tuning' – there's so many possible approaches, & many new tradeoffs to consider, that don't have easy/standard answers. (How do you choose/adjust proper balance between influence of starting vectors, & the new data? How do you ensure later-adjusted vectors stay 'in compatiblility' with those receiving fewer, or no, recent adjustments?)

Comment: I originally wrote the `.intersect_word2vec_format()` method for my own experiments. But all my results were mixed, and I've not come across any well-done explanations, since, of how & when it (or similar techniques) could be counted on for necessarily-improved results. It's all highly-dependent on the specific, improvised, careful steps an expert user might take – double-checking at each step if they're actually getting the hoped-for benefits. (If you know of or come across a good writeup, I'd love to see it – but most just plow ahead assuming things are working without robust analysis.)

Comment: Appreciate the detail and historical perspective. As I'm just getting started I was going to fall into the "plow ahead" camp in following the example code I was studying. I can now approach that example with a little more nuance.

Comment: What example code are you using? Does it make credible claims, with analysis, that the extra complication of starting-with-other-vectors helps?

Comment: No, it doesn't include analysis or commentary on whether a different choice would have been better. The code is here: https://github.com/Tixierae/deep_learning_NLP/blob/master/CNN_IMDB/cnn_imdb.ipynb. I found it through a linking to an arXiv paper on CNNs for NLP.

Comment: Aha. As far as I can tell, that notebook never even performs `Word2Vec` model training, instead just borrowing that class's initialization, then using the import of some `GoogleNews` vectors, to provide the starting vaues for a *different* deep-CNN training. That avoids many of my concerns, but results in some fairly indirect/unclear/overwrought code - like how it reuses `Word2Vec`'s random-initialization, but tries to guess where it happened by a crude magnitude check.

Comment: Still, if adapting that code for *any* other dataset/classification task, I'd not assume that the notebook's assertion that with `use_pretrained`, "convergence is faster, and absolute accuracy is slightly greater" holds true. It could be very contingent, and so the extra steps of re-using (some) `GoogleNews` vectors might be a time/space/code complexity with no net benefit.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. That gives me more context to understand that example.